# Rails - Create record from javascript prompt

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dialog

Let's say I have a product model, and the user selects its category in a combobox. The category has only one field, the name.
I would like to have a "add" button next to this combo to let users add another category just by typing its name in a javascript prompt dialog, so the category is inserted in the database and the combo is updated.

What's the best way to achieve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: have a look here fro remote forms: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

Comment: Thanks for the link, great article. But I'm still not sure how I would insert an category to the database and update the combo by clicking a button inside the product form. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

so this is what i understand from the question.. you want to create a record in your table when used clicks the add button. And the value of the record should be the name the user gives in the prompt dialog.

you can achieve this by doing this..

1) make an ajax call to the server side when the user enters the name.. if you use jquery, probably something like this..

```
    $.post("yourcontroller/yourmethod", { name: "value given by user in the prompt"}, function(data) {
       //this is where you update the combo
    });
```

2) Declare yourcontroller/yourmethod route in the config/routes.rb..

3) Define yourmethod in your controller which reads params[:name] and based on the ORM you are using creates a record in the table. if you are using Sequel ORM, you might do something like this.

```
YourTable.create(
  :name => params[:name]
)
```

that should then create a record in your table.